# Ошибка при задании длины динамического массива в паскале

Tags: pascal

```
type massiv = array of integer;
var a: massiv;
    n: integer;
begin
writeln('Введите длину массива');  readln(n);
setlength(a, n);
end.
```

Выходит ошибка: ожидался символ [

Answer (score 0):

Разобрался, нужна была актуальная версия IDE